# Is there a way to manually call an overlap event in Ue4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have two actors that are overlapping at begin play. I can get the Overlapping Component(s) easy enough but, is there a way to manually call an OnComponentBeginOverlap event since it doesn't get called at BeginPlay if they are already Overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

No, just create a separate event that follows the same execution as your OnComponentBeginOverlap event.